# Creating a function that loops through an array and flags index's that are do not match a criteria

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function that returns false if the hours of this business are different. So for instance if the business hours today are a little bit different than tomorrow, then it should return false. I'm working with some endpoints that provide me with the data I need for the next seven days and am trying to use a while loop to loop through them and match each against each other.  I keep running into an error while I try writing this loop in the console stating that there is an end of input error.

```
while (hours[i].start) {
  if (hours[i].start) == (hours[i+1].start)
    test_object = false
  end
}
```

The error i'm getting is an `unexpected token ==`

I've always been weak with JS looping, would anybody be able to help me through this situation?

Comment: `end` in javascript? what is it doing?

Comment: you forgot the parenthese in your if, replace it with: `if ((hours[i].start) == (hours[i+1].start))`

Comment: You forgot to enclose your `if` condition in parentheses, for one thing: `if ((hours[i].start) == (hours[i+1].start))`  I'm not sure about the rest of that syntax either though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a bracket

```
if ((hours[i].start) == (hours[i+1].start))
```

Also remove the end. The while loop would stop once the condition doesn't satisfy. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while)

```
while (hours[i].start) {
  if ((hours[i].start) == (hours[i+1].start))
    test_object = false
}
```

Comment: So I took a look at what you had. First off thank you (i'm more of a Ruby developer, and so always don't do the best with JS). When I tried what you had, at first I got an error stating that `i` was undefined. I then set it to `0` before running the loop....only this kept crashing it.

Comment: We are happy to help. JS takes a little time to get a jest of it :) . Can you provide sample data? If you can provide what you are expecting, and data you are handling, I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Edit

```
while (hours[i].start) {
  if (hours[i].start) == (hours[i+1].start)
  test_object = false
 end
}
```

to

```
while (hours[i].start) {
  if ((hours[i].start) === (hours[i+1].start))
    test_object = false
}
```

Also remove the end statement. There is no end keyword in javascript

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and check every pairs.

```
var test_object = hours.every((h, i, hh) => !i || h.start !== hh[i - 1].start);
```